# Creating an array of strings with an integer as element count, how to avoid case 0?

Tags: c++

```
string filler(string x1,int b)
{
    int pc=count(x1.begin(),x1.end(),'{');
    if(pc==0) goto skip;
    string x2[pc];
    return x2[b];
    skip:
    return "";
}
```

I know that this won't compile because it crosses initialization of a variable. But that's exactly the effect that I want to emulate. I want to check if there's `{` character in a string and if there isn't, I don't wanna define such variable. It's simpler to use something like `if(pc==0) string x2[pc];` but that's useless because `x2` is defined just within the `if` scope and I need to use that potential `x2` variable outside that scope.

So how to do that? Or can it be ever done?

Comment: What's wrong with `if (pc == 0) return string();`?

Comment: No, it can't be done. You can't have a variable that can either be declared or not declared at a certain point depending on runtime input.

Comment: You are using variable-length arrays which are a compiler-specific extension and not standard C++. The behavior of `goto` with variable-length arrays would be a matter of compiler-specifics as well.

Comment: I understand, thanks... Then I'll figure something else out. No need for further answers :)

Comment: Please don't answer your question in the question. If you have an answer you can post it as an answer yourself. If you don't want any answers, you can delete the question.

Comment: And on a side note: How did you think of using `goto` before the simple approach mentioned above? Using `goto` at all is very unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@1201ProgramAlarm's comment was helpful and it made me realize that something simple that I didn't think of. This does exactly what I want:

```
string filler(string x1,int b)
{
  int pc=count(x1.begin(),x1.end(),'{');
  if(pc==0) return x1;
  string x2[pc];
  return x2[b];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to check if there's { character in a string and if there isn't, I don't wanna define such variable.

That is achieved by declaring the variable inside a branch:

```
if (condition) {
    type varname;
} else {
    // varname was never created here
}
// if varname was created, its lifetime has ended
```